# Filtering by property value using neography

Tags: neo4j, neography

I'm testing with a simple variation of a working neography example, and while the filter seems as though it should work, I'm not having any luck. I can filter on position.length and it works fine, but I'm now trying to filter based on a node property.

Given these nodes:

```
node1 = Neography::Node.create("name" => "node1")
node2 = Neography::Node.create("name" => "node2")
person1 = Neography::Node.create("name" => "Person1", "role" => "author")
person2 = Neography::Node.create("name" => "Person2", "role" => "author")
person3 = Neography::Node.create("name" => "Person3", "role" => "editor")
Neography::Relationship.create(:user, node1, person1)
Neography::Relationship.create(:user, node2, person2)
Neography::Relationship.create(:user, node1, person3)
Neography::Relationship.create(:user, node2, person3)
```

With "the_node" set to person1, I'm trying to get this to return person3:

```
the_node.both(:user).
    order("breadth first").
    uniqueness("node global").
    #filter("position.length() == 2;").
    filter("currentNode.getProperty('role') == 'editor';").
    depth(2).
    map{|n| n.name}.join(', ')
```

The commented-out filter returns person3 as expected (2nd-level relationship), but the filter based on the 'role' property seems to filter everything so the result is empty.

Any suggestions would be terrific; I'm definitely new to neo4j and neography.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the traversal endpoint, I would look into cypher, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html, which is supported by Neography

Your query would then be something like

```
start user = node(1) 
match user-[:user]->person 
where person.role = "editor" 
return person.name
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks very much. I had looked into Cypher, so I've gone back to it but it's not quite working. Just to test I simplified it further:

Comment: Sorry, the formatting got all messed up, let's try again. I had looked into Cypher, so I've gone back to it but it's not quite working. Just to test I simplified it further:
`cypher_query =  "START me = node({node_id})"
cypher_query << "MATCH me-[:user]->(person)"
cypher_query << "RETURN person.name"
neo.execute_query(cypher_query, {:node_id => node_id})`
But it's returning nil, which has me a little stumped...
Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I just figured out that the relationships were unidirectional so it wasn't quite working, and I fixed that and it works! But now I'm trying to make the equivalent of depth(2) work in order to get the person through the connecting node, with no luck. Shouldn't this work: `cypher_query << "MATCH me-[:user]->(n)-[:user]->(person)"`. Thanks again for any ideas.

Comment: what about 'MATCH me-[:user*2]->person' see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-match.html#match-variable-length-relationships?